# attempt to import csv using django-import-export results in tablib.core.InvalidDimensions

Tags: django, csv, django-import-export

I am trying to import some csv data into a postgresql database using django-import-export. I am using python 3.4, django 1.8.1, and import-export 0.5.1.

My settings file has the following directive:

```
IMPORT_EXPORT_USE_TRANSACTIONS = True
```

my model has 10 fields. Postgresql autoincrements an 11th field, the id.

```
class BankTransaction(models.Model):
    tacct     = models.ForeignKey(MetaAcct,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tdate     = models.DateTimeField('tdate')
    tctpty    = models.ForeignKey(Counterparty,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    TRANSACTOR_CHOICES = (
        ('XXX', 'transactor1'),
        ('YYY', 'transactor2'),
    )
    tuser     = models.CharField(max_length=3,choices=TRANSACTOR_CHOICES,default="LMH")  # eg LMH
    trec      = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    tnote     = models.CharField(default='',max_length=50, blank=True)
    tcheckno  = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    ttype     = models.ForeignKey(TransactionType,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tamt      = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2) 
    tmemo     = models.CharField(default='',max_length=20, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        label = str.join(',',(str(self.tacct),str(self.tctpty)))
        return label
```

In admin.py I whitelist 8 fields, including the id field:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from import_export import resources

from .models import MetaAcct,Counterparty,TransactionType,BankTransaction

admin.site.register(MetaAcct)
admin.site.register(Counterparty)
admin.site.register(TransactionType)
admin.site.register(BankTransaction)

class MetaAcctResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = MetaAcct

class BankTransactionResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = BankTransaction
        fields = ('id','tacct','tdate','tctpty','tuser','trec','ttype','tamt')
```

My shell commands come right out of Read-the-docs:

```
>>> import tablib
>>> from import_export import resources
>>> from mny.models import BankTransaction
>>> banktransaction_resource = resources.modelresource_factory(model=BankTransaction)()
>>> dataset = tablib.Dataset(['','/Users/userid/Downloads/pa upload/test.csv'], headers=['id','tacct','tdate','tctpty','tuser','trec','ttype','tamt'])
```

The file I am trying to import, test.csv, looks like this:

```
id,tacct,tdate,tctpty,tuser,trec,ttype,tamt
,test,2015-01-13 0:00:00,TEST_ACCT,XXX,20151031,xfer,20000
,test,2015-01-31 0:00:00,BANK_ACCT,XXX,20151031,Int Inc,0.09
,test,2015-11-30 0:00:00,BANK_ACCT,XXX,20151130,Int Inc,1.49
,test,2015-12-17 0:00:00,TEST_ACCT,XXX,20151231,xfer,12000
,test,2015-12-31 0:00:00,BANK_ACCT,XXX,20151231,Int Inc,0.2
,test,2016-01-31 0:00:00,BANK_ACCT,XXX,20160131,Int Inc,0.24
,test,2016-02-29 0:00:00,BANK_ACCT,XXX,20160229,Int Inc,0.23
,test,2016-03-31 0:00:00,BANK_ACCT,XXX,20160331,Int Inc,0.25
,test,2016-04-08 0:00:00,TEST_ACCT,XXX,20160427,xfer,-6000
,test,2016-04-30 0:00:00,BANK_ACCT,XXX,20160430,Int Inc,0.2
,test,2016-05-31 0:00:00,BANK_ACCT,XXX,20160531,Int Inc,0.2
,test,2016-06-30 0:00:00,BANK_ACCT,XXX,20160630,Int Inc,0.19
,test,2016-07-31 0:00:00,BANK_ACCT,XXX,20160731,Int inc,0.2
,test,2016-08-31 0:00:00,BANK_ACCT,XXX,20160831,Int Inc,0.2
,test,2016-09-30 0:00:00,BANK_ACCT,XXX,20160930,Int Inc,0.19
,test,2016-10-31 0:00:00,BANK_ACCT,XXX,20161031,Int Inc,0.2
,test,2016-11-30 0:00:00,BANK_ACCT,XXX,20161130,Int Inc,0.19
,test,2017-01-30 0:00:00,TEST_ACCT,XXX,20170131,xfer,15000
,test,2017-01-31 0:00:00,BANK_ACCT,XXX,20170131,Inc Inc,0.21
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/userid/Documents/django/testenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tablib/core.py", line 169, in __init__
    self.headers = kwargs.get('headers')
  File "/Users/userid/Documents/django/testenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tablib/core.py", line 338, in _set_headers
    self._validate(collection)
  File "/Users/userid/Documents/django/testenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tablib/core.py", line 286, in _validate
    raise InvalidDimensions
tablib.core.InvalidDimensions
```

Because of testing, the latest id in the database model is 21, so the next auto-increment should be 22.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if you may be using the tablib [Dataset](http://docs.python-tablib.org/en/latest/api/) object incorrectly. Try this...

```
tablib.Dataset(headers=['id','tacct','tdate','tctpty','tuser','trec','ttype','tamt'])\
    .load(open('/Users/userid/Downloads/pa upload/test.csv').read())
```

Check out the [tutorial](http://docs.python-tablib.org/en/latest/tutorial/) to see other examples.

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion permitted me to get as far as populating a tablib dataset object with my test.csv file. Thanks also for introducing me to the tablib tutorial. Now I must figure out what is stopping the data from reaching the database. That will probably be an import-export issue.